# Return value from map or other way

Tags: javascript, dictionary, return, lodash, cycle

I need to get a match from an array and I cannot see any better ways to do it.
I appreciate your help.
I have an array:

```
sqlConditions: ['!=', '<>', '<=', '>=', '!<', '!>', '>', '<', '=', '%', 'LIKE', 'IS NOT NULL', 'IS NULL', 'BETWEEN', 'IN']
```

and I am doing this:

```
hascondition = quadConfig.sqlConditions.map(function (condition) {
        if (fieldValue.indexOf(condition, 0) === 0) {
            hascondition = condition;
            fieldValue = fieldValue.replace(hascondition, '');
            return hascondition;
        } else if (fieldValue.indexOf(condition, 0) > 0) {
            console.log("condição mal formada, etc...");

        } else if (fieldValue.indexOf(condition, 0) === -1) {
            console.log("condição mal formada, etc...");
        }
        if (fieldValue.indexOf(condition.toLowerCase(), 0) === 0) {
            hascondition = condition.toUpperCase();
            fieldValue = fieldValue.replace(condition.toLowerCase(), '')
            return hascondition;
        } else if (fieldValue.indexOf(condition.toLowerCase(), 0) > 0) {
            console.log("condição mal formada, etc...");

        } else if (fieldValue.indexOf(condition.toLowerCase(), 0) === -1) {
            console.log("condição mal formada, etc...");
        }
    });
```

But I just need the value `hascondition` not an array. Is there a way to break map or return just the matched condition?

Comment: please add the missing variables as well.

Comment: fieldValue="like xin"

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean this?

```
let hasCondition = quadConfig.sqlConditions.some(c=>fieldValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(c)!==-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the `sqlConditions` array to a [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) pattern using the 
case insensitive flag (`i`). Then apply it to the statement using [RegExp#exec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec). The result will be `null` if none is found. If a result is found you can get the `index`, and check if it's 0. If a result is not found at index 0 return `null`, else return the `result[0]` (the result is an array).

```js
function findCond(statement) {
  var sqlConditions = ['!=', '<>', '<=', '>=', '!<', '!>', '>', '<', '=', '%', 'LIKE', 'IS NOT NULL', 'IS NULL', 'BETWEEN', 'IN'];
  
  var pattern = new RegExp('\b' + sqlConditions.join('|') + '\b', 'i');
  
  var result = pattern.exec(statement);
  
  if(!result || result.index !== 0) {
    console.log("condição mal formada, etc...");
    return null;
  }
            
  return result[0];
}

console.log(findCond('<> 3'));

console.log(findCond('between something'));

console.log(findCond('xxxx between something'));

console.log(findCond('cats'));
```